# What exactly happens when functions are assigned to the list in Python?

Tags: python

I'm studying basics of Python and trying to understand Python frames.

I can draw environment diagrams for some basic flow, but I'm confused with lists.

Below is the code block.

```py
def square(x):
    return x*x
foo = square
x = [square, foo]

print(x) # [<function square at 0x1234..>, <function square at 0x1234...>]

foo = 5

print(x) # [<function square at 0x1234..>, <function square at 0x1234...>]
```

I think the last line should print '[<function square at 0x1234..>, 5]' because foo has been changed.

As far as I think, when assigning foo to the list, a new function pointer(I'm not even sure this is the right word for Python) is created and assigned the same value which `foo` has. And this new function pointer is assigned to the list.

Am I right?

If so, it seems like the only way to change the content of a list element is to access using `x[0]` syntax and modify it. Is is also right?

Comment: `foo = 5` reassigns the identifier `foo`, which does **not** change the value (the function named `square`) it previously referred to, nor does it change what `x[1]` refers to. Read e.g. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html. `x`, as the output suggests, contains a reference directly to the function object, _not_ to the name `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

The line `foo = 5` has updated the value assigned to the variable `foo`, but the array `x` is still containing a reference to the original `function` object, which is not updated when you change `foo`.